# I created ressources on aws in an organization but my colleagues don't have acces to them

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-organizations

It seems like a dumb question, but my friend set up an aws organization account, made me join it, and then i created ressources inside my account. Since my billing was "paid" by the organization, i thought the ressources were available to anybody inside the organization. It seems it doesn't work like that and, after research, although i'm pointed to IAM management, i don't see a way to organize it and make sure this doesn't happen anymore.
So my questions would be, am i the owner of those ressources or is the organization. How can i make it so that the organization handle those ressources??
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

> am i the owner of those ressources or is the organization

You are.

> How can i make it so that the organization handle those ressources??

Depends on what you mean by handling here :-)
If you're the owner of a resource and your organization have sharing enabled, then you can share this resource with absolutely any AWS account (you can limit sharing within organization). See details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/ram/latest/userguide/getting-started-sharing.html).